# Parsing adds AM/PM to the datetime for unknown reasons

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this piece of code:

```
string testdate = File.GetCreationTime(filePath + file).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
DateTime test1 = DateTime.ParseExact(testdate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

On testdate I have the following date: `2017-12-15 09:57:20.626`

Now when I try to parse it into datetime this is the result:

test1: `12/15/2017 9:57:20 AM`

What I want as result is the exact date on testdate but as a DateTime variable

Why is that happening if I'm using HH for the 24h format? I've seen many post removing the AM and PM, but with a string, I need it as datetime for a query.

EDIT:
Sql Server Query I'm trying to run

```
SELECT Transnum 
FROM transactions
WHERE (txnnum = @Txnnum and txndatetime between @InitDate and @EndDate)
```

Comment: _"Sql Server Query I'm trying to run"_ dont convert your DateTime to string to pass this into your sql query. Use parameterized queries, one reason: avoid sql injection

Comment: I appreciate the concern, it's made like that because I'm developing a internal service to manage orders and such, there shouldn't be any problems if there are no user input.

Comment: @KevinMiranda SQL injection is not the *only* thing parameters solve; they also solve formatting / i18n / l10n issues - i.e. exactly the problem you're having *right here*. And a few other things re performance. I waxed lyrical on this subject a few days ago: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DateTime` doesn't "have" am or pm in terms of explicit additions - it just is *the time* as a pure number; and the time it represents will either be in the am or in the pm.

It is only showing that in your output because *the output format* (perhaps defaulted, or in the debugger) includes that.

If you don't want to *display* am or pm, then: change where-ever is *displaying* `test1` to include a format specifier.

Comment: In that case, how do I know if I run the query with test1 it will be in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"? Because I the query uses an between begining_date to end_date and the adapter requires it to be datetime

Comment: @KevinMiranda what is "the query" here? is this for SQL by any chance? if so: [use a parameter](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html) - i.e. add a parameter with the value typed as a `DateTime`, and just refer to `@start` (or whatever) in the SQL. If it **must** be a string: then use one of the `.ToString(...)` overloads that accepts a format specifier

Comment: Added the query to the question. InitDate and EndDate are required as datetime or it shows an error

Comment: @KevinMiranda great; now - with any regular ADO.NET provider, all you need to do is `.Parameters.Add()` or whatever, specifying the `.Value` of the parameter as `test1` - it will never be a string: it is just a `DateTime`. If that isn't working: what ADO.NET provider is this? it sounds like it is broken. Some providers allow just `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InitDate", test1);` for example

Comment: this is the code that calls the query `Info.GetTransactionNumber(Int32.Parse(file.Substring(6, 4)), date.Date, date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1))` (trying to do like '2017-12-15 00:00:00.000' and '2017-12-15 23:59:00.000'

Comment: @KevinMiranda the relevant code is the code that *adds the parameters*. I can't see that from the signature.

Comment: @KevinMiranda btw, a better way to do that is usually `where SomeDate >= @start and SomeDate < @end` - note the `<`; this means you don't need to mess with `AddTicks(-1)`.

Comment: Note that Marc's advice is not purely about readability: When serializing dates between applications and databases, there is a risk that the minimum Date granularity won't match.  For example, in SQL Server, `datetime` has a granularity of 3ms.  Thus, `select cast('2000-01-01 23:59:59:999' as datetime)` will round to `2000-01-02` though (`select cast('2000-01-01 23:59:59:999' as datetime2)` will not round).  In fact, the granularity of `datetime2` is configurable, making it even more difficult to generate a `time - epsilon` calculation.